# Azure DevOps - AzureBlob File Copy task fails while copying files to blob storage

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-blob-storage

I am creating a release pipeline on Azure DevOps for deploying ReactJs App. I have two tasks in my release pipeline: Download Build Artifact task and AzureBlob File Copy task. The AzureBlob File Copy task throws the following error:

> Upload to container: '$web' in storage account: 'XyzContainer' with
> blob prefix: '' failed with error: 'AzCopy.exe exited with non-zero
> exit code while uploading files to blob storage.

Please see the following screenshot:

[image]

Following are the settings for the AzureBlob File Copy task:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I made the following two changes to AzureBlob File Copy task settings and it worked!

Change #1: Downgrade the task version from 4 to 2.

Change #2: In the container name field, add quotation marks with the container name. For example: from web --> "$web"

[image]

Comment: This worked for me too!  Im surprised MS haven't fixed the broken V4 yet.

Answer (score 1):

Version 3 works as well.

There's still a bug with version 4.  and with version3, you don't need to add quotation marks to the container name